# Composer update showing wrong php version

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I've installed XAMPP `v3.2.2` with PHP `7.0.21` and `composer 1.5.1` and building an application on `laravel version 5.4.36`.

While installing `spatie/laravel-analytics` package i'm getting error:

```
  Problem 1
- This package requires php >=7.0 but your PHP version (5.6.4) does not satisfy that
 requirement.
Problem 2
- Installation request for spatie/laravel-analytics ^3.1.0 -> satisfiable by
 spatie/laravel-analytics[3.1.0].
- spatie/laravel-analytics 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.21) overridden 
by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I had a line:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
     ................
    }
```

on my `composer.json` file. Reading from a post on [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/upgrading-laravel-php-version) I changed "php": ">=5.6.4" to "php": ">=7.0" and ran command `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`
and getting the error message:

```
 Problem 1
- This package requires php >=7.0 but your PHP version (5.6.4) does not satisfy that 
requirement.
```

I would be very thankful if anyone could point out what is causing this error and its possible solution.

Comment: Obviously you have installed PHP 5.6

Comment: run `php -v` to get your current version.

Comment: Output of php -v   `PHP 7.0.21 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2017 13:31:19) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Sounds like there is a system root definition variable stuck with the 5.6.x version in it.  Check your Apache server to see if it recognizes the PHP version correctly, verify any Configuration files have the appropriate PHP Version stated, as well.

Comment: @GoldBishop How do I check PHP version from apache server ?

Comment: All i know is how Apache behaves on Windows Servers....sometimes the Path variables clog up the versioning system...were PHP reports one version (`php -v`) and Apache will report another (`phpversion()`).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall composer and select manually php7 folder

Comment: I reinstalled XAMPP and there's only php folder. No php7 folder.

Comment: @TanjaForsberg that may not be a literal reference to select `php7` folder but instead where you have installed PHP-7.